# Python, Writing contents of function to .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing some online tutorials with python 3.5 and have learned how to write a string to a file and save it. Now I am trying to write the contents of a function but don't have any luck.

```
from RECAPS import recap3_1

recap3_1.get_details("Mark", "M", 26)
recap3_1.get_schooling(30000,260,900)

fw = open("Details.txt", "w")
fw.write(recap3_1.get_details("Mark", "M", 26))
fw.close()
```

I then get this error

```
Mark Male 26
Traceback (most recent call last):
29360
File "E:/PyProjects/YoutubeProject/RECAPS/recap3.py", line 8, in <module>
fw.write(recap3_1.get_details("Mark", "M", 26))
Mark Male 26
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the get_details function is just this,

```
def get_details(name, gender, age=0):

if age < 18:
    print("You are too young to register")
    return

if len(name) < 2:
    print("Looks like your name is too short")
    return

if gender is "M":
    gender = "Male"
elif gender is "F":
    gender = "Female"
else:
    gender = "Unknown"

print(name, gender, age)
```

What am I missing. I was hoping to grab the function from another .py file and save the contents

Comment: what does get_details do?  you need to paste more code

Comment: @HaifengZhang on it

Comment: If `get_details` doesn't return a string, but `None` (i.e., nothing), there is obviously nothing to write to file. Your question is likely how to return a value from a function, not how to write something to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post, I can see `get_details` do print output on console but it can't tell whether it returns anything or not.

```
def get_details(name, gender, age):
    info = "{0} {1} {2}".format(name, gender, age)
    print(info)  # print on console
    return info  # you have to return a String
```

Python Input and Output:

> f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written.

```
>>> f.write('This is a test\n')
>>> 15
```

Comment: Works brilliantly, I didn't know you could write functions like that.

Comment: you only need add one line to your `get_details` method: `r"{0} {1} {2}".format(name, gender, age)` then your code will work

Comment: another quick question before I leave you, is there a way to make the next write go to a new line? I tried adding "\n" to various places in my fw.write but doesn't seem to work like when you just write a string

Comment: do f.write(string_line + "\n")

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling: `recap3_1.get_details` is returning `None`, not the value you want to write to file. Just because the values print to the screen does not mean that you are returning these strings when calling the function. Try:

```
    test_var = recap3_1.get_details("Mark", "M", 26)
    print(test_var)
```

You should see `None` print to the screen. If you want the `get_details` method to return a value to write to file, you have to specify in the method definition.

EDIT:
Now that you've posted your code, you need your method to return a string... if you want the values space separated like your printed output, just do:

```
    return ' '.join((name, gender, age))
```

instead of the print statement in `get_details`, and your script should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the functions `recap3_1.get_details` and `recap3_1.get_schooling` print to `stdout` directly instead of returning strings, that's why you're getting a `None` instead of a string. In order to write their result, you need to get their output as a string. Can you modify their code?